# Acumatica: How to insert/update customer using EMAIL as key VIA Web API?

Tags: c#, acumatica

I am using the Screen based API to import customers.  I would like to use the e-mail address as the identifying key when submitting via the API.  In other words, when submitting the customer, it will use the email address to determine if that customer already exists or not.

Basically I want to accomplish what is in the following website, but using the Screen based API instead:
http://www.timrodman.com/importing-new-customers-email-address-acumatica/

My code is as follows:

```
        using (Screen context = WebServiceConnector.InitializeWebService())
        {
            try
            {
                AR303000Content customerSchema = context.AR303000GetSchema();

                // ATTEMPT #1: Tried setting the CustomerID field name to "AcctCD!EMail"
                customerSchema.CustomerSummary.CustomerID.FieldName += "!" + customerSchema.GeneralInfoMainContact.Email.FieldName;

                // ATTEMPT #2: Tried setting the CustomerID field name to "AcctCD!Contact__eMail"
                //customerSchema.CustomerSummary.CustomerID.FieldName = "AcctCD!Contact__eMail";

                // Tried COMMIT = true and false
                customerSchema.CustomerSummary.CustomerID.Commit = false;

                // Left as default and tried "ID"
                customerSchema.CustomerSummary.CustomerID.Value = "ID";

                var commands = new List<Command>()
                {
                    new Value
                    {
                    Value = customer.Email,
                    LinkedCommand = customerSchema.CustomerSummary.CustomerID
                    },
                    new Value
                    {
                    Value = customer.Name,
                    LinkedCommand = customerSchema.CustomerSummary.CustomerName
                    },
                    new Value
                    {
                    Value = customer.Class,
                    LinkedCommand = customerSchema.GeneralInfoFinancialSettings.CustomerClass
                    },
                    new Value
                    {
                    Value = customer.Email,
                    LinkedCommand = customerSchema.GeneralInfoMainContact.Email
                    },
                    new Value
                    {
                    Value = customer.CountryCode,
                    LinkedCommand = customerSchema.GeneralInfoMainAddress.Country
                    },
                    customerSchema.Actions.Save,
                    customerSchema.CustomerSummary.CustomerID
                };

                c = context.AR303000Submit(commands.ToArray())[0];

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                context.Logout();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should configure the search of a customer record by email
address:
a. Before the code that creates the commands array, save the initial field name of the CustomerID field in the string variable initialCustomerIDFieldName.

b. After the definition of the initialCustomerIDFieldName variable, initialize the properties of the Field object with the values of the properties of the CustomerID key field.

c. Concatenate the FieldName property of the Field object (which is now equals the value of the FieldName property of the CustomerID key field) with ! and the FieldName property of the FilterEmail service command.

d. In the Value command inside the array of Command objects, set the Value property to the customerMainContactEmail variable (which is set to info@jevy-comp.con) and the LinkedCommand property to the created Field object.

The following code illustrates this procedure.

```
AR303000Content custSchema = PX.Soap.Helper.GetSchema<AR303000Content>(context);
//Save the initial field name of the CustomerID field string 
initialCustomerIDFieldName = custSchema.CustomerSummary.CustomerID.FieldName;
//Configure the command that searches for a customer record
//by using the FilterEmail service command
Field customerIDSelector = custSchema.CustomerSummary.CustomerID;
customerIDSelector.FieldName += "!" +
custSchema.CustomerSummary.ServiceCommands.FilterEmail.FieldName;
var commands = new Command[]
{
    new Value
    {
        Value = customerMainContactEmail,
        LinkedCommand = customerIDSelector
    },
};
```

There is more information and examples in [Acumatica online course for Screen-Based API](http://acumaticaopenuniversity.com/courses/i200-screen-based-web-services/)